# Puedo subir archivos usando php y ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: photoProfile in **C:\xampp\htdocs\web\profile.php** on line **8**

Al intentar subir un archivo usando ajax me aparece ese error y no sube el archivo, pero probando a hacerlo sin ajax, y si funciona correctamente, me podrían indicar si sería posible realizar esto con ajax.

```js
var form = $('#form'),
        data = form.serialize(),
        url = 'backend/profile.php';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            console.log("Exito");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El formulario es el siguiente:

```html
 <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            <table class="highlight">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Email:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="inputEmail" type="text" name="email" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Foto de perfil</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="file-field input-field">
                                                <div class="btn">
                                                    <span>Imagen</span>
                                                    <input type="file" id="inputProfile" name="photoProfile">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Foto de portada</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="file-field input-field">
                                                <div class="btn">
                                                    <span>Imagen</span>
                                                    <input type="file" id="inputFront" name="photoFront">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div id="error" class="center"></div>
                            <div class="row center">
                                <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Guardar datos</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

El php:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require 'class/functions.php';
require 'class/users.php';

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phProfile = $_FILES['photoProfile'];
$phFront = $_FILES['photoFront'];
user::changProfile($user,$phProfile);

?>

//Función para subir la imagen

function changProfile($user,$photo){
    $route = "../accounts/$user/profile/";
    $namePhoto = $photo['name'];
    $nameTemp = $photo['tmp_name'];
    $namePhoto = $photo['name'];
    $upload = "$route/profile.jpg";
    return $result = move_uploaded_file($nameTemp,$upload);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto que si, me parece que tu código quedaría de esta manera:

```
$("#form").bind("submit", function() {
    var data = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'backend/profile.php',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function() {
            console.log("Exito");
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Verificarlo y nos avisas, saludos!

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error :/

Comment: Actualice el código,  aunque no leí bien anteriormente, el error que te marca es que la variable photoProfile no esta definida, esta dentro de tu formulario?, puedes compartir el código de tu form?

Comment: Listo, edité la pregunta añadiendo el form y sí está el input con el name que dice no estar definido.

Comment: Si esta muy extraño, puedes compartir tu PHP?

Comment: Añadido, el php sólo guarda en unas variables los datos de los input y ejecuta la función para subir la imagen. Probé el código que pusiste y aunque ahora no me bota ningún error, no hace nada, no sube el archivo :/

Comment: jeje Ok, lo que pasa vamos por menos, ya no te marca ese error por que ya reconoce la variable a través del objeto FormData(), sin ello solo procesa los inputs tipo $_POST, ahora el que no suba el archivo, debe ser algún error en tu query, puedes compartirlo?

Comment: Ya la añadí, pero yo la habia probado sin usar ajax y si funcionó correctamente.